# IE8 jQuery place cursor in a textbox possible only at the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, cursor, position

I'am on my limit.
I have to implement some features for a web application. Problem is, it can only be implemented for IE8 because of company policies...
IE8 does even not load jsFiddle normally. I get any possible and unintelligible errors.
I have a lot of php scripts and as an response (ajax-request) from one of it I get a table with some data.
If I click on this element a editbox appears and I can modify this value.
First problem is, that I can only modify this value if I click on this element at first, but I can not set the cursor anywhere else. It is at the beginning at first. If I click anywhere else in the box, cursor disappers and I can't do anything.
I thought it is a problem in my code. But... I have just copied some relevant code to a new file (I can not post entire code here because of policies and copyrights) and I get some silly errors like "Object expected" although the value is already an object!

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./JavaScript/jquery-1.9.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function modify(value){
    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(value).addClass('ajax');
    $(value).html(
            '<input id="editbox"' + ' type="text" value="' + $(value).text() + '"/>');
    $('#editbox').focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="test" border="1">
<tr>
<td class="ajax" id="test" onclick="modify(this)">Click</td>
<td>Nothing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tset" onclick="modify(this)">Click</td>
<td>Nothing</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, help me someone... I simply does not understand, why I can not place the cursor normally. <strike>and why I'am getting such stupid errors</strike>. <strike>I looked into the debugger and anything was idetically with the other call (from ajax-php), but here it won't proceed on $(value)....</strike>

**First problem with the "object expected" solved**
*src="-->**.**<--/JavaScript/jquery-1.9.1*
Was just a point.

But now you can see my problem with the cursor. How can I get the same as when I just have a normally "textbox" (input type="text" value="blabla".....) and I simply can set my cursor wherever I want

**Edit**
Got something interesting. As it seems to be I have to work with **$('#editbox').focus();**

Anyone an idea how to free the cursor?

Comment: you have two td with the same id which is not valid html. Actually even the table has the same id...

Comment: sorry, error from copy+paste, I have corrected it, all problems stil there

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your script to something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function modify(value){
   //$('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
   //$('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
   $("#" + value.id).addClass('ajax');
   $("#" + value.id).html(
           '<input id="editbox"' + ' type="text" value="' + $("#" + value.id).text() + '"/>');
   $('#editbox').focus();
}
</script>
```

When you pass an html element to a function, it doesn't pass a jQuery object, just a DOM object.  Using $("#" + value.id) finds the DOM object and converts it to a jQuery object.

Comment: If you're gonna be looking for `$("#" + value.id)` all the time, you should probably cache it somewhere.